# Express middleware for express.static() not routing correctly and throwing next() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Despite this running correctly on my local machine while I was writing and testing it, it seems to fail when deployed out to our UAT environment using Docker. I can't seem to track down why it's giving me the following:

```
next() is not a function
```

I also seem to be having a routing issue (again only when it's deployed) where even if it when the route is /media/public it seems to still hit the /media route.

dependencies

```
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1"
```

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const { join } = require('path');
const { fileExists, isAuthenticated } = require('./helpers/utils');
const { PORT, ROOT_SHARE } = process.env;
const app = express();

global.__basedir = __dirname

app.use('/robots.txt', function (_req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.send('User-agent: *\nDisallow:/');
});

app.use('/media/public', [fileExists, express.static(join(__dirname, ROOT_SHARE, '/public'))]);
app.use('/media', [isAuthenticated, express.static(join(__dirname, ROOT_SHARE))]);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.info(`[File Server] : running on ${PORT}`));
```

utils.js

```
const { existsSync } = require('fs');
const { verify } = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { join } = require('path');
const { ACCESS_SECRET, NODE_ENV  } = process.env;

const fileExists = async (req, res, next) => {
    let mediaFile = (NODE_ENV === 'local') ? join(__basedir, req.baseUrl, req.path).replace('\\src','') : req.originalUrl;
    console.log(mediaFile);
    if (!existsSync(mediaFile)) {
        console.log('NOT FOUND')
        return res.status(404).send('NOT FOUND');
    }

    return next();
}

const isAuthenticated = async (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = valueOrNull((req.cookies && req.cookies['x-access-token']) || (req.headers && req.headers['x-access-token']));
    
    if (!accessToken) {
        console.log('accessToken not found')
        return res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED');
    }

    try {
        fileExists(req);
        const { user } = verify(accessToken, ACCESS_SECRET);

        if (user) {
            console.log('VALID USER');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED');
    }

    return next();
};

const valueOrNull = (value) => {
    return (typeof value == 'undefined' || value === null || value === '') ? undefined : value;
}

module.exports = {
    fileExists,
    isAuthenticated
}
```

.env

```
ROOT_SHARE=../media
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /media

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force --loglevel=error

RUN npm install -g pm2

COPY src /app/src

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "src/server.js"]
```

exact error
[image: next() is not a function]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call:

```
fileExists(req);
```

but your implementation of `fileExists()` expects you to pass it `(res, res, next)` and you are not passing that.  Thus, you get the error `next() is not a function` when `fileExists()` tries to call `next()`.

It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do, but perhaps you can change to this where you pass `(req, res, callback)` to `fileExists()` and then you continue your processing in that callback.  That's how you manually call middleware yourself which it appears you are trying to do:

```
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = valueOrNull((req.cookies && req.cookies['x-access-token']) || (req.headers && req.headers['x-access-token']));
    
    if (!accessToken) {
        console.log('accessToken not found')
        return res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED');
    }

    try {
        fileExists(req, res, () => {
            const { user } = verify(accessToken, ACCESS_SECRET);

            if (user) {
                console.log('VALID USER');
            }
            return next();

        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED');
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `fileExists` is being used both as a middleware and as a function called in `isAuthenticated` — in `isAuthenticated` it's not being passed `res` or `next`. If you do pass it there, you may end up having other issues, since both functions call `res.status(status).send()`. You also have some `async` keywords on those functions when they're not `await`ing anything — that's not breaking anything, it's just a waste of a few characters :).